# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am getting No parameterless constructor defined for this object error while posting data. It is working fine on get. I am using service pattern in my project and using unity container for handling dependency injection. I have registered all the services in container.

Stack Trace :-

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +239
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindSimpleModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult) +285
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +284
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +377
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1210
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +336
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +346
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_1(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +403
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +427
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163
```

As suggested in some articles i have also created the constructor for my model but no luck.

My Controller (GET)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        var ct = _ctService.getctdetails();

        var viewModel = new HomeviewModel()
        {
            itemsList= GetItemsList(),
            ctDTO= ct 

        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

POST:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(HomeviewModel values)
    {


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

ViewModel:-

```
  public class HomeviewModel
 {
    public productDetailsDTO { get; set; }
    public CreationDTO ctDTO{ get; set; }
    public SelectList itemsList{ get; set; }
  }
```

Controller Constructor

```
 public HomeController(ICTService ctService,
        ITemsService itemService)
    {
        _ctService= ctService;
        _itemService= itemService;
    }
```

In My view i am just using the itemslist and setting values in DTO , fetching some data using ajax if we change the selected item and submitting form, the control is coming to the controller constructor but after that giving error,not going to the post method.

Comment: Could you mention your dependency injection setup?

Comment: It might be that the `SelectList` which is present in the `HomeviewModel` is causing this exception. Maybe you should try changing it to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Answer (score 0):

use Castle.Windsor :

```
 private readonly IIocManager _iocManager;
     ICTService _ctService= _iocManager.TryResolve<ICTService>() ??
                             throw new UserFriendlyException("UnknownActionType");
     ITemsService _itemService= _iocManager.TryResolve<ITemsService>() ??
                             throw new UserFriendlyException("UnknownActionType");
    public HomeController()
        {
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

in asp.net mvc controller you must add constructor without parameters.
You should add this constructor :

```
public HomeController()
{


    _ctService= new ICTService() ;
    _itemService= new ITemsService() ;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this defeats the purpose of dependency injection. The whole point of receiving interfaces in the constructor is to decouple the controller from the concrete implementations of its dependencies. `new` in the constructor couples it tightly.